# Troubles "redirecting" a connection

Tags: c, sockets, unix, server, client

I've got some new troubles for you. I'm studying sockets and TCP/IPv4 in C. I have to write a battleship game and I'm quite excited about it. But I can't really solve some problems. So this is my situation.
I've got one server and multiple clients. Each client can challenge or be challenged from another client. The server waits for a client to write an univoque ID. Once the ID is written, the server scans an array of     `struct sockaddr` and finds the one related to the previously read ID. Then it calls `inet_ntoa()` to make the IP a string and writes it to the client. Once the client has read the IP, it creates a new direct connection with the other client and starts playing battleship. 
Okay so this is the scenario. What I'm struggling with, is first how to get a univoque IP address out of that `inet_ntoa()`, since I'm executing every client instance in a terminal on the same host machine. Second, every client should accept incoming connections from other clients. So I gave each client 2 sockets: one for the client-server communication, and one that listens for the possible pending connections (This socket will be put in a `readfd` of a `select()` ).  The thing is, once I start a new client istance -if another client is already connected and waiting to challenge or be challenged - I have to specify the IP of the server the client will connect to. So, whether I use `127.0.0.1` or the host machine IP address, the new istance of the client tries to connect to the already connected client (since its socket is in a `listen` state) and not to the server. I think it has to do with ports, but I don't know how to achieve what I want to do (Already tried to change ports etc.).
Here are some lines of the code. I omitted obvious things (don't kill me for this last sentence, please).

CLIENT CODE:

```
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, claddr,cl2addr;
servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET; //used for the client-server connection
servaddr.sin_port=htons(8888); //port 8888 for the client-server communication
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]); //argv[1]=IP of the server
cl2addr.sin_family=AF_INET;  //this will be used for the client-client new connection
cl2addr.sin_port=htons(9990);//listen on the port 9990
cl2addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY; //for any client to connect
servsock=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
listenfd=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if (bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr*)&cl2addr,sizeof(cl2addr))<0)
{
    perror("Binding: "); //This printf "Address already in use"
    exit(-1);
}
if (listen(listenfd,1)<0)
{
    perror("Listening: ");
    exit(-1);
}
if (servsock<0)
{
    perror("Creating socket: ");
    exit(-1);   
}
if (connect(servsock,(struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr))<0) //estabilish a connection with the main server
{
    perror("Connect: ");
    exit(-1);   
}
//some code with the select etc. inside //
if ((mastfd=accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *) &claddr,&cllen))<0)
    {
        perror("Accept: ");
        exit(-1);
    }
```

SERVER CODE:

```
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, claddr[10]; //che claddr array holds every IP in the sin_addr.s_addr field
int conn=0;
servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port=htons(8888);
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
listenfd=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0); 
if (listenfd<0)
{
    perror("Socket: ");
    exit(-1);
}
if(setsockopt(listenfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char *)&opt,sizeof(opt))<0)
{
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(-1);
}
if (bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))<0)
{
    perror("Bind: ");
    exit(-1);
}
if (listen(listenfd,10)<0)
{
    perror("Listen: ");
    exit(-1);
}
//here goes a while loop//
{
    FD_SET(listenfd,&readfd);   
    select(maxfd,&readfd,NULL,NULL,&elaps);
    accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&claddr[conn],&len);
    conn++;
    //here the server waits for a client to write the ID to challenge, find the relative position in the claddr array and then writes the ip to the client//
    m=strlen(ipbuff);       //calculate the lenght of the IP
    nwrite=write(att,&m,sizeof(m)); //write the lenght to the client
    if (nwrite<0)
    {
        perror("Writing LEN: ");
        _exit(-1);
    }
    nwrite=write(att,ipbuff,m); //write the IP to the client
    if (nwrite<0)
    {
    perror("Writing IP: ");
    _exit(-1);
     }
}
```

Ps.
Very often, the  IP written from server to client has `len=2` and is something like `00` or `0.0.0.0` . This is due to the fact that it returns the local machine ip address, right?
Thank you guys, by the way. If code is bad indented or other things, feel free to throw s*** on me.

Comment: pluse uno for your code formatting , but minus uno for rambling description of  your problem. Is the core of your problem "how to get a univoque IP address out of that inet_ntoa()"? Please show the minimal code for that problem, your current output and the expected output. That's all we need, right? :-) ... Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter is correct that your question is not well-described but a few observations... There's no way that the IP address can possibly be correct with a length of 2. An IPv4 address in binary form will always be 4 bytes -- and you cannot use `strlen` to measure its length. In text form (from `inet_ntop` for example), it will be at least 7, likely larger. "Local machine address" is ambiguous since the machine may have several addresses, but perhaps you mean the loopback address? That is conventionally "127.0.0.1" (binary length = 4, text length = 9).